# How can I install an exterior porch light where there is no junction box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, junction-box

I live in an older house with small, exterior porch light fixtures outside 3 doors.  Those fixtures need to be replaced.  When I pulled the first one off, I found 2 wires coming thru the wall - no junction box containing the connections.  I understand I cannot replace them this way as it doesn't meet code - I need the connections to be contained.  Is there any type of box I can add to the exterior of the wall vs cutting a larger hole?  Are there any exterior fixtures that have the box as part of the fixture itself so that a junction box isn't required?  Suggestions?

Comment: "2 wires" - are these individual wires? Or is a **cable** with two wires inside it? Any sign of a ground wire?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the existing wiring?

Comment: Two individual wires.  One black - one white.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. a photo) before we can help you more. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What kind of siding? I just added some exterior boxes in a case just like yours using arling8141 this works on lap siding I think they also have them for t1-11

Answer (score 2):

At the hardware store, ask for an "old work" box, sometimes also called a "cut-in box", they are made to be added to existing walls / ceilings and have little clips on the side that allow you to anchor them into the hole. You will need to make the proper size hole as well, typically with what's called a "keyhole saw" if you are OK with a manual operation, otherwise you would use a "reciprocating saw" or now, a "roto-zip" saw. If you don't have one, you can often rent them.